# retrofit v/s async task for one request

Tags: android, retrofit

I am already aware of the advantanges of retrofit and have used it in many scenerios. For a particular application , I need to call only 1 login API which will do authentication.

I am not sure if the advantages of retrofit are worth it for only one API. or is it a overhead and I should Http for sake of simplicity

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it is just a single request, then I'd say go with the simplest/lightest approach. But these things tend to evolve with time, therefore you are likely to find yourself in a position of adding another one, then another one...

Remember - networking mechanism is not an architectural decision. In fact, your application should not care what networking mechanism is being used - it should depend on a general interface that you define. You could start with implementing this interface using the simplest approach, and add a more complex implementation in case your networking requirements evolve. You could also implement several approaches and benchmark them...

So, whatever approach you choose, I recommend not to "pollute" your business logic with networking logic, but hide it behind interface. This way even if you make the wrong decision now, it will be a matter of few hours to fix it later.

Answer (score 1):

For a single API call http is fine. As you know using library with your application is going to occupy user phone space when they install your application on their device. so for a single call, you are good to go with async task.